# Returning last value by filtering in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a database from which I have extracted the unique values of customer account. I am trying to filter through the same excel file by customer account and get the email id of that customer through loop.

my excel data (customers.xlsx) looks like this:

```
ClientID          email
abc               abc@email.com
dcf               dcf@email.com
ghj               ghj@email.com
```

and this my code:

```py
import pandas as pd  
customer account = []  
file = pd.read_excel(customers.xlsx)  
customer_account = file['ClientID'].unique().astype(str)
```

I am trying to loop through unique value of customer account and get the corresponding email id of that customer.

I tried searching online but no solution found.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

To get the e-mail of the user abc, just do this:

```
email_abc = file[file['ClientID' == "abc"]['email']
```

Which means: in dataframe `file`, select all rows where `ClientID` equals `"abc"` (there will be only one here if all IDs are unique), and return the content of column `'email'`.

Since there is only one row, the result will be of type string (in other terms, you'll get the content of the single cell obtained). If there were several rows, then the result would be a Series (equivalent of a Python list) and you would have to choose which element of this Series you want. Hence it is important to be sure that the IDs are all unique.

Variant: if IDs are unique, you can use them as index of your dataframe. In that case the code to retrieve the value is:

```
file = file.set_index('ClientID') # Set column ClientID as index
email_abc = file.loc['abc'] # get row with index "abc"
```